# Transforming using function "parse-json" returns error

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am attempting to process JSON data directly by using function "parse-json".
I have linted the JSON so it's syntax is correct. Adding text values in the elements instead of querying the JSON data, makes the outcome being produced but not with JSON data.

**JSON data:**

```
<data>
{
    "general": {
      "Language": "English",
      "Country": "Sweden"
    },

    "units-definitions": {
      "SEK": "42B"
    }
  }
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:root="http://www.example.org/1"
  xmlns:flat="http://www.example.org/2"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <root:report>
      <xsl:variable name="json" select="parse-json(.)"/>

      <!-- These works -->
      <!-- <flat:Country>1</flat:Country>
      <flat:SEK>2</flat:SEK> -->

      <!-- These does not work -->
      <flat:Country>{?general?Country}</flat:Country>
      <flat:SEK>{?units-definitions?SEK}</flat:SEK>

    </root:report>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result**

Blank output

**Visible error:**

```
Saxon-HE 10.5J from Saxonica
Java version 11.0.11
Error at char 1 (on line 22) of file:[Xxx.xsl] 
  XPTY0004  The left-hand operand of '?' must be a map or an array; the supplied expression
  is of type element(Q{}data)
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
[Finished in 0.828s]
```

**Expected result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root:report xmlns:flat="http://www.example.org/2" xmlns:root="http://www.example.org/1">
   <flat:Country>Sweden</flat:Country>
   <flat:SEK>42B</flat:SEK>
</root:report>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `$json` variable. Put it to the left of the `?`:

```
<flat:Country>{$json?general?Country}</flat:Country>
<flat:SEK>{$json?units-definitions?SEK}</flat:SEK>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to show in which context your original attempt would work: if you push your `parse-json` directly through `apply-templates` and match on an XDM map the snippet works in the context of that template:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:root="http://www.example.org/1"
  xmlns:flat="http://www.example.org/2"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <root:report>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-json(.)"/>
    </root:report>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(xs:string, item())]">
    <flat:Country>{?general?Country}</flat:Country>
    <flat:SEK>{?units-definitions?SEK}</flat:SEK>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Good reminder/example of predicate patterns. I seem to forget about those.